# flex MS Project library

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, ms-office, flex4, ms-project

Is there ActionScript library that works with MPP(MS Office Project)? library that parses MS Project XML?

Also please advice me all links that may help me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a library per-se, but I just happened to implement something along these lines this week. I wrote a simple script to parse exported MSProj CSV files into XML and then sent that XML into my Flex application. Maybe you can do something similar on the server side.

I doubt you will find a native AS3 class that parses the proprietary binary format of Project, so some intermediate format might be necessary here.